# VB.net - storing values

Tags: vb.net

I've been using the following method to store the primary key value of whatever record is being referenced. I would then call the Content.Id method to retrieve that value for sql commands.

My question is - is this good practice? One other told me I should make a session item instead.

This is my ContentDA class

```
Public Shared Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _ContentId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _ContentId = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This is Content class

```
Public Shared Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return ContentDA.Id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        ContentDA.Id = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: @ramipaul: it's not clear what you're asking. Are you able to post the relevant parts of the class that's performing the SQL commands?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

If you're asking, "Is it good practice to reference records by primary key?" then yes.  A unique value is necessary when searching through record collections, and primary key is as good as any.

If you're asking, "Is it better to save the commands as global variables and reference them that way?" then no, it's not necessarily better or worse; just different.

Personally, I'd go with the first method, myself.

Comment: Thanks for replying - I believe you've answered my question. To clarify I was trying to determine if using a public shared property to store a value was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your general design as far as having a data access class that is directly referenced by the domain/business layer class. However, I was caught off guard by the `Shared` nature of the declarations of each. It is not typically accepted practice having static/singleton classes used in this manner. Afterall, you can only ever have one `Content` or `ContentDA` loaded at any given time in the application domain the way you currently have it set up.